# How to add an Image with Fabric JS that is absolutely inert for interaction

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

Is it posible to add an Image with Fabric JS that is absolutely inert for any kind of interaction ?

What do i mean ? First we add Image :

```
let image1 = fabric.Image.fromURL(src1, function (img) {        
    img.set({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
    });
    canvas.add(img)
})
```

And then , another Image right over previous one

```
let image2 = fabric.Image.fromURL(src2, function (img) {        
    img.set({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
    });
    canvas.add(img)
})
```

Now i set Mouseclick listener on canvas like that :

```
canvas.on({
'mouse:down': (options) => { console.log(options.target) }
})
```

... so if we click on our image2 (that is right over image1) , options.taget is , of course , pointing to image2.

But what i need is that this click ignores image , that was placed over first one and we could interact straight with image lying below

looks like it  is possible to override a fabric listener to achieve what i need , but i do not even know where to begin (my skill is too low) .

Would be grateful for any help, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set [`evented:false`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#evented) and [`selectable:false`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#selectable).

Pretty much self-explanatory.

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c")

const url = "https://via.placeholder.com/200x200"
const url2 = "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"

fabric.Image.fromURL(url, (img) => {
  canvas.add(img)
}, {
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  stroke: 'blue',
  strokeWidth: 1,
  evented: false,
  selectable: false
})

fabric.Image.fromURL(url2, (img) => {
  canvas.add(img)
  img.sendToBack()
}, {
  left: 150,
  top: 50,
  stroke: 'blue',
  strokeWidth: 1
})

canvas.on({
  "mouse:down": options => {
    console.log(options.target);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.4/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='c' width="300" height="250"></canvas>
```